# Role of single-valued factors in unitary method

Tags: arithmetic

The question here, is very basic in nature but I really can't get the intuition behind it.

Consider the following translations:-

Degree swept by hour hand in 1 hr:-

$12 hr = 360^\circ$
$1 hr = \frac{360^\circ}{12hr} * 1hr = 30^\circ$

Degree swept by hour hand in 1 min:-

$1 min = 30^\circ * \frac{\frac{1}{60}min}{1 min} = 0.5^\circ$

---

In the 1st translation, 1hr is **multiplied** with the fraction while in the 2nd translation, 1 min *divides* the fraction.
Notice that even without using these 2 factors, there would be no change in the answer, more precisely, no change in the magnitude of the answer.
While using *unitary method*, multiplying or dividing with such single-valued factors is a normal step in evaluating the answer, often not shown to make steps less verbose.

But, my question is *are these factors there only for to cancel out the like units so to bring out the required unit in the answer* or *is there any significance about these single-valued factors **(like any information these factors are encapsulating)**?*

Also, if there isn't any significance about these factors, *can it be said that they are just being used out of necessity to have a more complete consistent answer without any information that can be deduced from them?*

Answer (score 1):

I think you made an error.

Consider this: $\displaystyle\frac{360º}{12 \,\text{hours}}=\frac{30º}{1 \,\text{hour}}.$

Alternatively, you could try $360º \times \frac{1 \, \text{hour}}{12 \, \text{hour}}=30º$.

You'll cancel out the units or end up with the same unit combination on each side.

Even for the last conversion, $\displaystyle \frac{30º}{1 \,\text{hour}}\times\frac{1 \, \text{hour}}{60 \, \text{minutes}}= \frac{0.5º}{\text{minute}}$

Comment: so, is it that these single-value factors exists out of proportion and not in any arbitrary way which I think, is being reflected in my question?
If it's like that then I suggest you to add few more examples to make it more clear